# Android auth_token validation and usage server-side

Tags: android, google-api, oauth-2.0

How can I validate the auth_token returned from

```
token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
```

?

After I get the new user on Android I need to insert them into my database server side, but I need to validate that token somehow before I do.

I am trying to use the token like this:

```
url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=%s' % access_token
```

but Google is returning 'Unauthorized Access'.

How can I access

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
```

using the Android AccountManager provided 'auth_token' ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can use that token for other services outside Android, I may be wrong though.

Comment: I think you're missing the 'oauth2:' scope prefix. See answer below.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably just missing the `oauth2:` prefix in front of your authTokenType.

This code works:

```
// Note the `oauth2:` prefix
private static final String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE_USERINFO_PROFILE =
    "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";

// TODO: allow the use to choose which account to use
Account acct = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google")[0];

accountManager.getAuthToken(acct, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE_USERINFO_PROFILE,
    null, this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
      @Override
      public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
        try {
          String accessToken = future.getResult().getString(
              AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
          Log.i(TAG, "Got OAuth2 access token: " + accessToken);
          /*
             Your code here. Use one of two options. In each case replace ... with
             the above OAuth2 access token:

             1) GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=...

             2) GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo with this header:
                Authorization: Bearer ...
          */
        } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
          // TODO handle this case
          Log.w(TAG, "The user has did not allow access");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO handle this exception
          Log.w(TAG, "Unexpected exception", e);
        }
      }
    }, null);
```

}

Comment: This was the answer, why dont i have to register my app at [**API Console**](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). Is that because im not accessing any Google Apis but only getting userinfo json?

Answer (score 1):

The token returned from AccountManager is a ClientLogin token, not an OAuth token. So you can not use the API related to OAuth. But you can still fetch calendar data, contact data, or other data supported by ClientLogin.

For example, if you get "cp" for contacts, on the server, you can use

```
curl -H 'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth="Your_ClientLogin_token"' https://www.google.com//m8/feeds/contacts/default/full
```

Using Zend Gdata, you can do it by

```
$client = new Zend_Gdata_HttpClient;
$client->setClientLoginToken($token); // $token is your ClientLogin token
$gdata = new Zend_Gdata($client);

// perform query and get result feed
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Query('http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full');
$feed = $gdata->getFeed($query);
```

However, using ClientLogin token on the server-side is not recommended, as mentioned here:

- https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq?csw=1#which_auth_mech
- https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq?csw=1#AuthClientLoginWebapps

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use it to get the user info using the Google API.  Normally an OAuth 2.0 bearer token is inserted into an Authorization HTTP header when calling a RESTful API.

See the sample provided here: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/AndroidAccountManager

Comment: I don't have a problem getting the user, I have a problem getting the user server side, where I need to prove the auth_token the Android AccountManager gave me is valid.  I can't just go accepting whatever auth_token someone posts to my server pretending to be a phone, it needs to be validated in some way.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate.html#ConnectToService  is an example, but I have no clue what 'your_api_key' is and I need to work with Contacts, not Tasks.

Comment: The sample I pointed to original indicates this: "Once your application has the "auth token" for an end-user, it should pass it to GoogleHeaders.setGoogleLogin(String)."  I suspect that just puts the access token an HTTP Authorization header (e.g.: Authorization: Bearer your-access-token).  Again, this is how you call an OAuth protected API.  The token attached in the header will identify the user to Google and should return to you the required user info when you invoke their service.

Comment: So in theory, I should be able to pick my flow server side right about here: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.html#userinfocall ?

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work.  I tried using the URL string method and the Authorization: Bearer method, neither work for me.  I get 'Unauthorized' either way.

Comment: What about "Authorization: OAuth xxxxxxx".  Older drafts/implementations of the OAuth 2.0 spec do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got things working using this method:

https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/oauth-practices/mobile-apps-for-complex-login-systems/samplecode