# How can I access the Google account user_id?

Tags: android, oauth, openid, accountmanager

I'd like to access the user's Google account [`user_id`](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) for [authentication](https://developers.google.com/accounts/), but I don't see any mention of this in the [`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

How can my app request the `user_id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/package-summary) is available, you can use it to request the user's permission to access the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` scope and, with the resulting access token, make a request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token={accessToken}` to get their user ID.

Comment: Is the `userinfo?access_token={accessToken}` request documented somewhere?

Comment: The documentation for userinfo is provided here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#userinfocall

Comment: I [noticed](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/) `Note: Google Play services has not launched, but we want to give you a quick overview of what to expect.`  Does this mean the API is not yet available, or that it's in some kind of beta state?

Comment: @JeffAxelrod That is correct. The documentation for the API is now available, but that's it. For now, use the Android AccountManager's getAuthToken API. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10988589/313790

Comment: @JeffAxelrod FYI: Google Play services is now available for developers. You will want to take a look at GoogleAuthUtil, and the AccountPicker.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the Android AccountManager's [getAuthToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) API until Google Play services is released.

Here's an example of how you can use getAuthToken to obtain an `access_token`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10988589/313790

Answer (score 1):

Check out Google's [AccountManager example for the Tasks API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android).

Once you have an access token, you then instead of using the Tasks library, use the [oauth2 library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#oauth2) of google-api-java-client to request a [`Userinfo`](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/oauth2/v2/index.html) object like in [this example](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/oauth2-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/oauth2/cmdline/OAuth2Sample.java?repo=samples):

```
Oauth2 oauth2 = new Oauth2.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
   .setApplicationName("Google-OAuth2Sample/1.0").build();
Userinfo userinfo = oauth2.userinfo().get().execute();
String userId = userinfo.getId();
```